# Box2D: Creating the b2BodyDef inside an object causes error

Tags: c++, constructor, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am using cocos2d with Box2D to create a simple iPhone game, and have made GameLevel objects which contains LevelObject objects.

I want to create level objects with the constructor

```
LevelObject(CGPoint position, b2BodyType type, b2Shape* shape, CCSprite *sprite);
```

as I believe this contains all the information I need to create the object on the screen.

```
LevelObject::LevelObject(CGPoint position, b2BodyType type, b2Shape* shape, CCSprite *sprite) : position(position), sprite(sprite) 
{
sprite.position = position;

bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
bodyDef->type = type;
bodyDef->position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
bodyDef->userData = sprite;

fixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef;
fixtureDef->shape = shape;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run this, I get a SIGABRT-error. But if I move this

```
bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
bodyDef->type = type;
bodyDef->position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
bodyDef->userData = sprite;
```

outside the constructor, and pass in the bodyDef in the constructor:

```
LevelObject::LevelObject(b2BodyDef* bodyDef, CGPoint position, b2BodyType type, b2Shape* shape, CCSprite *sprite) : bodyDef(bodyDef), position(position), sprite(sprite)
```

Everything works as intended.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any difference in creating the bodyDef = new b2BodyDef inside or outside the constructor?

EDIT: I cannot seem to edit the bodyDef object inside the constructor neither. If I create bodyDef outside, take it in as a parameter, then

```
bodyDef->position.Set(134/PTM_RATIO, 33/PTM_RATIO);
```

and so on inside the constructor doesn't change how the object looks on the screen.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more of the code from before you call this constructor. For example, how was the b2Shape* created, are you deleting any of these pointers somewhere, is something going out of scope etc. About the last part (your edit), are you doing that after you create the body by any chance? The body def is only used when you call CreateBody, after that the body never looks at it so you would need to use functions of the body eg. body->SetTransform etc to change it.

Comment: Code from before the constructor:

    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"floor.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
        CGPoint position = ccp(200,200);
        b2BodyType type = b2_staticBody;
        b2BodyDef* bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
        bodyDef->type =  type;
        bodyDef->position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
        bodyDef->userData = sprite;
        b2PolygonShape* rectangle = new b2PolygonShape;
        rectangle->SetAsBox(320/PTM_RATIO * 0.5f, 20/PTM_RATIO);

And my intention was to do the bodyDef code inside the constructor.

Comment: I should have also asked where the error occurs.

Comment: Does this help?
Assertion failed: (b2IsValid(bd->angularDamping) && bd->angularDamping >= 0.0f), function b2Body, file /Users/Username/Folder/Xcode/Application_name/Application_name/libs/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, line 32.

Comment: It looks like somehow the values in the b2BodyDef you are passing to CreateBody are messed up. b2IsValid just checks if the value is NaN. Don't be afraid to follow the Box2D source code a little, it's not entirely physics voodoo :) Of course, I am assuming you did not set the angular damping to a negative value. I can't see any obvious problems in the code you have shown so far, but check that the bodyDef pointer you made with 'new' is not being deleted or messed up somewhere before you call CreateBody.

Comment: I tried writing all my code from scratch, and now it works... Don't know what was wrong, as I cannot fin any difference from the code I wrote her :P

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `new` to create a b2BodyDef. In the [Box2D API Reference](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/structb2_body_def.html) you'll see that b2BodyDef is a struct, not a class.

This is how you should create a b2BodyDef and any other Box2D struct:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = type;
bodyDef.position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
bodyDef.userData = sprite;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I do it in this way and call the constructor with the bodyDef variable, it's like creating a emtpty b2BodyDef (I'm guessing it's because I want a pointer to the bodyDef, not a copy of the struct). Doing this inside the constructor gives the same error as before.